# Website does not Load

Tags: networking, firefox, dns, proxy, redirection

The [URL to this site](http://web.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os.html?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os) does not load consistently while it works when using proxy.

Error message are:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> IceDragon has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can
>   sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
>
> IceDragon v. 26.0.0.2

---

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can
>   sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
>
> Firfox v. 34.0.5

---

according to (TCPIPUTILS.com) site IP 4 information is:

Network information

- **IP address**: 77.67.27.17
- **Reverse DNS (PTR record)**: not available
- **DNS server (NS record)**: sns-pb.isc.org (192.5.4.1), pri.authdns.ripe.net (193.0.9.5), ns3.nic.fr (192.134.0.49), sec3.apnic.net (202.12.28.140), sec1.apnic.net (202.12.29.59), tinnie.arin.net (199.212.0.53)
- **ASN number**: 3257
- **ASN name (ISP)**: Tinet SpA
- **IP-range/subnet**: 77.67.0.0/17 (77.67.0.0 - 77.67.127.255)

---

Any idea what can be causing this specific error?

Comment: Have you tried disabling cookies?

Comment: there was no cookie notification at either browser.

Comment: What do you mean "no cookie notification"?

Comment: Cookie notification is a browser message that tell user if particular site require the use of cookies or not. BlackBerry App World plugin by Research in Motion--for Firefox usually does a good job beyond the conventional use of cookies.

Comment: There has been long-lasting issues with blackberry connectivity. one of them was recorded by me at his link.                  https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5t3tfnorz3kfny/blackberry-01-11-2015.FLV?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

When Firefox has reported a page isn't redirecting properly, [I've found that removing any "block" entries for cookies from the site to which the page is trying to redirect and instructing Firefox to allow cookies from that particular site may resolve the problem](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/firefox/not-redirecting-properly/). You can view the source code for the page where you encounter the problem to determine the site to which it will attempt to redirect visitors by right-clicking on the page and selecting "View Page Source."

Once you determine the site to which redirection will occur, you can check the cookie settings for that site by clicking on the Firefox menu button (the three short, horizontal lines one below the other) at the top, right-hand corner of the Firefox window, then clicking on **Privacy**.

Then select "Use custom settings for history" from the drop down list in the **History** section. Put a check in the check box next to "Accept cookies from sites," if it isn't checked already, and set "Accept third-party cookies" to "Always."

Click on the **Exceptions** button and look for the relevant domain name in the list of exceptions for cookies and if you find any entries marked as "Block" for the site, select those and click on **Remove Site**.

Note: though the entries are in alphabetical order, there are separate HTTP and HTTPS sections, so you need to check both those sections.

After removing any entries for the site, add new HTTP and HTTPS entries, but with **Allow** specified rather than **Block**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but adding my two cents here… My guess is that the web server is simply redirecting the request to the destination so many times, the browser gives up. This is not an issue idiosyncratic to any specific web browser, but in general it is bad practice to endlessly redirect URLs to a final destination.

For example, I ran this this Curl command to do a header check:

```
curl -I -L "http://web.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/ute/blackberry10-os.html?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os"
```

And that command results in 7 (!!!) redirects of a mixed type; some being 301 permanent and others being 302 temporary. That’s utterly nuts. In my experience as a web developer and systems administrator, that many hops jumping between 301 and 302 redirects with switches between HTTP and HTTPS along the way is a problem waiting to happen. The reason why a proxy *might* work is because somehow the proxy is closer to the source web server in some way and thus results in less redirect hops in its journey.

The reason why some browsers choke on it might be varying degrees of security logic in their core that tell them when to declare a website problematic due to excessive redirects. Solving the issue would need to be idiosyncratic to each browser and it’s own settings.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://us.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os.html?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:34 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://us.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os.html?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: blackberry_iso={"country":"US", "state":"NY", "city":"NEWYORK"}

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://us.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os/?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) Communique/4.1.12
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:40 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: blackberry_iso={"country":"US", "state":"NY", "city":"NEWYORK"}

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://us.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os/?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:40 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: blackberry_iso={"country":"US", "state":"NY", "city":"NEWYORK"}

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://us.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) Communique/4.1.12
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: blackberry_iso={"country":"US", "state":"NY", "city":"NEWYORK"}

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://us.blackberry.com/software/smartphones/update/blackberry10-os?cpid=van:bb:Jan2014:vanity:bb-update:blackberry1021os
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: blackberry_iso={"country":"US", "state":"NY", "city":"NEWYORK"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
ETag: "2b0c5-554269064f350"
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 22:44:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) Communique/4.1.12
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 176325
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 16:33:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: blackberry_iso={"country":"US", "state":"NY", "city":"NEWYORK"}
```